# Create relation between three tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have three models: menu, submenu and post. Menu can have many submenus, menu has one post and each submenus has one post too. How can i set up eloquent relations between each model and access data like all the subemenus of the menu and their corresponding post.

Comment: Hi Prajwol. Laravel has very extensive documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x
Did you already go through this? If so please provide some code examples of what you have already tried. Also check out the following guidelines on asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you had tried something show us your code so we can configure out where you getting the issue exactly.

Comment: i just created three models menu, submenu and post. what i want to do is display all the posts of each menu and submenu in a view. i am not getting how to do it. any example would be helpful.

Comment: @Prakeol edit and post your codes with your question